# If statment has invalid syntax

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Im am currently trying to make a game within pygame and am in the process of adding some music, the current code I have is this

```
    if self.room.running = True:
        self.music_sound = self.load_sound('Song.mp3')
        self.music_sound.play()
    else:
        self.music_sound.stop()
```

The idea is that when executed, the song would play until the room was no longer running and the player had moved onto the next level.

however, when I try to run the code, it comes up with this error

```
  if self.room.running = True:     
                       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

Try doing:

```
if self.room.running == True:
    self.music_sound = self.load_sound('Song.mp3')
    self.music_sound.play()
else:
    self.music_sound.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparison operators are used to compare two values.

The if statement may be combined with:

```
== equality,
>= greater than,
<= smaller than
!= not equal
```

The "=" sign used to assign values to variables.

Comment: Thanks for that, everything is now working

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
if self.room.running:
    self.music_sound = self.load_sound('Song.mp3')
    self.music_sound.play()
else:
    self.music_sound.stop()
```